# Excel: counting the "either or" occurrence of multiple criteria in column B while not double-counting duplicates in column A

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

Here's some sample excel data that I spun up to describe the problem that I'm facing.

| StudentID | Subject | ClassName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Math | Algebra I |
| 002 | Science | Biology |
| 002 | Math | Algebra II |
| 002 | History | US History |
| 003 | Math | Geometry |
| 003 | Science | Chemistry |
| 004 | English | Playwriting |
| 004 | Math | Trigonometry |
| 004 | Language | Spanish I |
| 004 | Language | Italian I |
| 005 | English | Playwriting |
| 005 | English | Speech Writing |
| 006 | Language | Linguistics |
| 006 | Science | Physics |
| 006 | English | Rhetoric |
| 007 | Language | Spanish II |
| 007 | Math | Pre-Calculus |
| 008 | History | World History |
| 008 | Language | French I |
| 008 | English | Mythology |
| 009 | English | Poetry |

- Every column uses the string data type

I'm struggling to figure out an excel function/formula that will count how many distinct students are taking **either a Math or Science course** but making sure to only **count each student once**. So for the above example data, there are **6 distinct students** who took either a Math or Science course.

Most of the information I've found online has solutions that are related to but not exactly what I want. This problem is simpler in a language like Python (where you can filter by subject and then de-duplicate the StudentID) but I'm having a hard time since I'm not super familiar with the nitty-gritty of excel functions.

I've tried playing around with various excel functions like countifs and sumproduct but haven't made much progress and nothing has worked so far.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Please let me know if any clarifications would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E2</kbd>

```
=ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A22,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(B2:B22,{"Math","Science"})))))
```

---

Another alternative using <kbd>MMULT( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E2</kbd>

```
=ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A22,MMULT(N(B2:B22={"Math","Science"}),{1;1}))))
```

---

Comment: Thanks for your help! Both of your provided formulas worked for my use cases.